# Split DataFrame column Julia

Tags: julia

I have a dataframe and i want to split the values of one column and get just the pos 2. I am trying to use split. but i think I am doing something wrong.

```
split.(barDF[!, :Dashname], "-")
```

This is what it returns.

```
6-element Vector{Vector{SubString{String}}}:
["3 ", " Monitor: Campaigns"]
["16 ", " Act: PAUSE Keywords"]
["24 ", " High Priority Action List"]
["7 ", " Inspect: Campaign Performance"]
["6 ", " Monitor: Search Terms"]
["2 ", " Oversee: Budget Pacing"]
```

if I try to insert [2] at the end of the split function it returns the seccond list instead the pos2 row by row.

Answer (score 1):

Try broadcasting the `getindex`:

```
julia> getindex.(split.(barDF[!, :Dashname], "-"), 2)
```

Example:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(
           a = ["foo-,-oof", "bar-,-rab"]
       )
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a
     │ String
─────┼───────────
   1 │ foo-,-oof
   2 │ bar-,-rab

julia> split.(df[!, :a], "-")
2-element Vector{Vector{SubString{String}}}:
 ["foo", ",", "oof"]
 ["bar", ",", "rab"]

julia> getindex.(split.(df[!, :a], "-"), 2)
2-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
 ","
 ","
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know there's only one dash in your data and you want the bit of the string after that you can just use `last`:

```
last.(split.(barDF.Dashname, "-"))
```